# Difference between $(window).width() vs $(document).width()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, dimensions

What is the major difference between `$(window).width()` vs `$(document).width()` in jQuery?
Whether window denotes the browser and document represents the body of html page? Am I correct ?

Comment: @PizzaiolaGorgonzola could you please explain about this " but it should not be used to structure your code, it encourages to write opaque, unreadable, hard to maintain, not object oriented code."

Answer (score 63, accepted):

From the [documentation of `width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/):

> This method is also able to find the width of the window and document.
>
> ```
> $(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
> $(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
> ```

[Simple jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xme7y/1/)

In the demo, I have set `html { width: 1000px; }`, which is bigger than the viewport.

The width of the body of your HTML page is a third value. `$('body').width()` can also differ from the other two (try `body { margin: 100px; }` for example).

Answer (score 22):

You are correct.  the `window` is the viewable area of the browser.  The `document` is the actually body of the page.  So your `document` could extend far beyond the `window`

Comment: SO why is the demo on jquery showing a window width smaller than browser width? http://screencast.com/t/PlTXAShwmeP7

Comment: @AlxVallejo if you look at the source you can see that the demo code is running in an iFrame that has the width of 568px.

Comment: the `document` could extend far beyond the `window` made things clear for me.

Answer (score 8):

> Well, the `window` is the first thing that gets loaded into the browser.
>   This `window` object has the majority of the properties like `length`,
>   `innerWidth`, `innerHeight`, `name`, if it has been closed, its parents, and
>   more.
>
> What about the document object then?
>
> The `document` object is your html document that will be loaded into the
>   browser. The `document` actually gets loaded inside the `window` object
>   and has properties available to it like title, URL, cookie, etc. What
>   does this really mean? That means if you want to access a property for
>   the `window` it is `window.property`, if it is `document` it is
>   `window.document.property` which is also available in short as
>   `document.property`.

So in conclusion the document could be smaller than the window.

FROM: http://eligeske.com/jquery/what-is-the-difference-between-document-and-window-objects-2/

Comment: Well, your aspx or php will still output an HTML document. It does not make a difference which language was used to create HTML.

Comment: That's true those languages are server side. Edited it tnx.

Comment: @Rick you should reference quotes, it's both useful and ethical: http://eligeske.com/jquery/what-is-the-difference-between-document-and-window-objects-2/

Comment: @TomHall Your right about that, added the link were I got the data from.

Answer (score 4):

`$(window).width();`   returns the width of browser viewport

`$(document).width();` returns  width of HTML document

`$(document).width()` is a bit unreliable, resulting in a lower value for a full-screened browser . $(window).width() is safer.

`$(window).width()` gets the entire width of the window, including things like the scroll bar .

Answer (score 4):

Another important difference.

`$(window).width();` is available before the document loads / is ready

`$(document).width();` is only available after the document had loaded

So for the second, you need

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var w = $(document).width();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes - width of window is width of browser window, and width of document is width of webpage.