# jQuery $("body").height() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a call like this:

```
$("#ContextMenuModal").height($("body").height());
```

However `$("body").height()` returns undefined when I view it in Firebug.

What would cause jQuery to return undefined for the body height?

I am using jQuery 1.4.1.

Edit:

This is inside an iFrame

Comment: Without seeing a test case, we can only have wild assumptions about what can cause this. Please create a demo or show the page. Here is a [demo that shows it working](http://jsfiddle.net/BBf3g/). Your turn.

Comment: @bažmegakapa It is a large application I am unable to post, I can attempt to create a repro, however, I was wondering if there were cases where jquery cannot determine the height.

Comment: It's always difficult (mostly impossible?) to find a bug when you cannot see the code and the program running.

Comment: Are you running this after the page has loaded?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply use

```
$(document).height() // - $('body').offset().top
```

and / or

```
$(window).height()
```

instead $('body').height()

To expand a bit,

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

As bažmegakapa points out, there is a slight difference, albeit a few pixels. The true height of the body can be calculated by subtracting the body offset from the document height (like I mentioned above):

```
$(document).height() - $('body').offset().top
```

Comment: -1 for showing the functions and not providing an explanation/description. There is a big difference between these two (well, three).

Comment: $(window).height() and $(document).height() are also both returning undefined for me

Comment: @Norse Few pixels, yeah. The document can be much higher than the viewport. And if you set `body { margin-top: 2000px; }`, I'd say the document will be much bigger than the body :). [A previous question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431050).

Answer (score 0):

Use this-

```
 $("body").css("height")
```

well i will say jquery is not needed-

```
this.style.height;//it will not work if you add it as inline js.
```