# Jquery body height returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jquery ver 1.10.2 and I need to know the height of the body, not of the window(!). I use the following code:

```
<script>
     window.onload=function(){
         alert($("body").height());
     }
 </script>
```

But I get 0. Can you help me?

EDIT: I have checked - document height can't be less that window height, but I need to know the difference between body height and window height, when body height < window height as I want to use js to make sticky footer.

Comment: try $(document).height();

Comment: You have contents inside body tag? If not it will return zero.

Comment: @DeDevelopers lose the quotes around `document`

Comment: Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023183/jquery-body-height-returns-undefined

Comment: is the contents of body floated?

Comment: @RGS: Yeah, I think the same. Yo're right!

Comment: @George Rosario No, that's not the duplicate. See my EDIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use

```
$(document).height() // - $('body').offset().top
```

and / or

```
$(window).height()
```

instead

```
$('body').height()
```

To expand a bit,

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

As bažmegakapa points out, there is a slight difference, albeit a few pixels. The true height of the body can be calculated by subtracting the body offset from the document height (like I mentioned above):

```
$(document).height() - $('body').offset().top
```

Comment: See the EDIT in my question.