# $(window) or $(document) to measure width and height to auto fit images in browser with every screen

Tags: jquery, html

I have to fit all the images on a screen with every screen resolution.

Which should i use `$(window)` or `$(document)` to measure `height /width` to auto fit images.

Comment: Why don't you give them both a try and see, using a button to toggle between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no fixed height for all the images, then use

```
$(window).load(function () {
    // your code goes here which will be executed once all the images 
   // got loaded (seen)
});
```

In case the height is fixed for all the images you are loading, then do  not wait for the images to be loaded, just assign fixed height to `<img>` tags and fit them. Use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // your code goes here which will be executed once the DOM is ready 
    // (means all the tags including IMG tags) are loaded. 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to get the $(window).

The `window` includes `document`. The `window` is the browser-screen, so the viewable area on screen, while `document` is your document. So the html page that is loaded into the browser, this can be smaller than your screen size.

Comment: See this has the same answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431050/difference-between-window-width-vs-document-width

Answer (score 0):

I use window like this:

```
function resizeThings(){
var  winH = $(window).height();
var  winW = $(window).width();

// let's say you are trying to match images to height
 $('img').each(function(){
   $(this).css('height', winH); 
 });
```

};