# Going over the window height increases the elements width?

Tags: css, html

**I have nothing on the page except two `section` elements.** Both the `sections` take up `1280px` of `width` and `800px` of `height`. When I shrink the browser window `width` down to `1281px` (using Chrome's Dev tool to see the window's width), a horizontal scroll bar appears as if I had shrank the windows `width` below `1280px`. When I inspect the `body` element it shows me that it is `1264px` in `width`. On the other hand, Dev Tool shows me that the window `width` is `1281px`.

When I decrease the `height` of both the `section` elements to a value lower than the window's current `height`, for example `300px`, the horizontal scroll bar disappears and the `body` `width` is shown to be `1281px`.

I have also applied css reset on the page as well.

what is causing this and how to prevent this?

```
section#sec1{
    background: orange;
}

section#sec2{
    background: pink;
}

section{
    display: block;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:1280px;
    height:800px;
}

<section id="sec1">Some content</section>
<section id="sec2">Other content</section>
```

If you want jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L991shcp/

and the reset:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post all of your CSS (what reset are you using for example?). Even better, can you create a jsfiddle? Clearly the problem is something other than the CSS/HTML you have posted, but it is impossible to say what unless we can see it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between $(window).width() vs $(document).width()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431050/difference-between-window-width-vs-document-width)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the horizontal scroll bar using:

```
 overflow: hidden;
```

This might prevent the issue you are facing.

Comment: This does not explain why the horizontal scrolling is happening (which is very difficult when the question is lacking information).